# Parsing the GnuPG secret key list

Tags: bash, awk, gnupg

You can get a parseable list of secret keys in GnuPG by doing:

```
gpg2 --list-secret-keys --with-colons
```

The format of the output is described here: http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/DETAILS

I want to write a bash function that tells me if I have both valid encryption and signing keys. Based on the above URL, this is what I came up with:

```
has_valid_secret_keys() {
  return "$(gpg2 --list-secret-keys --with-colons 2>/dev/null | \
            awk -F: 'BEGIN { sign = 0; encrypt = 0; }
                     ($1 ~ "sec|ssb") && ($2 ~ "[mfu]") {
                       if ($12 ~ "s") sign++
                       if ($12 ~ "e") encrypt++
                     }           
                     END { print !(sign * encrypt) }')"
}
```

That is, the Awk script matches secret keys and secret subkeys (field 1) with marginal, full or ultimate validity (field 2), then it maintains a counter of signing and encryption keys based on the matched records' capabilities (field 12). If both these counters are zero, then we have no signing or encryption keys, otherwise we have what we want.

This works great in GnuPG 2.1, but when I try it in GnuPG 2.0, the capability field doesn't appear to be set in the output of `--list-secret-keys`. It was quite hard work finding the documentation for the output; I presume it must have changed between v2 and v2.1.

Is there a GnuPG-version agnostic (including even GnuPG 1.4, if possible) way of doing this?

---

**EDIT** Thanks to Jens Erat's answer, my updated (i.e., working!) bash function is as follows:

```
has_valid_secret_keys() {
  # Check that both valid signing and encryption (sub)keys exist

  # Format described at http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/DETAILS
  # First we find the Key IDs of secret keys and subkeys, then we
  # reference these against the public keys to check their capabilities
  return "$(gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons 2>/dev/null | \
            awk -F: '($1 ~ "sec|ssb") { print $5 }' | \
            xargs gpg --list-keys --with-colons 2>/dev/null | \
            awk -F: 'BEGIN { sign = 0; encrypt = 0; }
                     ($1 ~ "[ps]ub") && ($2 ~ "[mfu]") {
                       if ($12 ~ "s") sign++
                       if ($12 ~ "e") encrypt++
                     }
                     END { print !(sign * encrypt) }')"
}
```

Comment: Link describing the format is dead. Is this a recent version? https://github.com/CSNW/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Documentation is Under Source Control

The copy of the document you linked for [GnuPG 2.1](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/DETAILS)is under source control, you can either look at the file's history or just fetch the [GnuPG 1.4](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;h=de0f21ccba60c3037c2a155156202df1cd098507;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4)/[GnuPG 2.0](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/DETAILS;h=645814a4c1fa8e8e735850f0f93b17617f60d4c8;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-2-0) branches' versions.

The colon output has not changed for quite some time (it is the most relevant part of what might be considered an "API" to interface the GnuPG binary). The capability field should return what you expect since (at least) GnuPG 1.4.

### GnuPG 2.1 Merged the Secret Keyring

The issue with the version difference is another one (and indeed, GnuPG 2.1's behavior changed here): while GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0 had a separate secret key store, this was merged into the public key store for GnuPG 2.1. WIth this change, some output changed. GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0 only list the capabilities when querying the public keyring; GnuPG 2.1 queries the same keyring both when listing public and secret keys and has the same information in its output for both commands.

If you need to support GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0, you will have to

1. query for secret keys and then
2. filter using the output of the public key listing.

Comment: Thanks :) I've added a working function, based on this, as an errata to my question.